# How to keep first observation of a variable in a data.table without deleting rows?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to remove all observations from a variable, except the first one. But this is where it gets tricky for me: I don't want to affect the rest of my data.table.

Is there an efficient way in data.table to go from my DTin to my DTout ?

I can't do it without deleting rows.

```
> DTin
    V1 V2
 1: aa  1
 2: aa  2
 3: aa  3
 4: aa  4
 5: bb  1
 6: bb  2
 7: bb  3
 8: bb  4
 9: cc  1
10: cc  2
11: cc  3
12: cc  4

> DTout
    V1 V2
 1: aa  1
 2:     2
 3:     3
 4:     4
 5: bb  1
 6:     2
 7:     3
 8:     4
 9: cc  1
10:     2
11:     3
12:     4
```

Here is the reprex :

```
library(data.table)

DTin <- data.table(V1 = rep(c('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), each = 4),
                   V2 = rep(seq(1:4), 3))

DTout <- data.table(V1 = c('aa', '', '', '', 'bb', '', '', '', 'cc', '', '', ''),
                    V2 = rep(seq(1:4), 3))
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
DTin[rowid(V1) != 1, V1 := "", by = V1]

#OR

DTin[c(1, diff(rleid(V1))) != 1, V1 := ""]
DTin

   V1 V2
 1: aa  1
 2:     2
 3:     3
 4:     4
 5: bb  1
 6:     2
 7:     3
 8:     4
 9: cc  1
10:     2
11:     3
12:     4
```

dplyr approach

```
DTin %>% group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(row_number() ==1, V1, "")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   V1       V2
   <chr> <int>
 1 "aa"      1
 2 ""        2
 3 ""        3
 4 ""        4
 5 "bb"      1
 6 ""        2
 7 ""        3
 8 ""        4
 9 "cc"      1
10 ""        2
11 ""        3
12 ""        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple split-apply-combine strategy. It's not clear to me if you want the substitution to be `NA` or some other value, which is why I parameterized this option.

```
DT <- split(DT, by= 'V1')
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(DT, function(l, sub= NA) {
  nr <- nrow(l)
  first <- l[, V1][1]
  l[, V1 := c(first, rep(sub, nr - 1))]
  return(l)
}, sub= NA))
print(DT)


      V1 V2
 1:   aa  1
 2: <NA>  2
 3: <NA>  3
 4: <NA>  4
 5:   bb  1
 6: <NA>  2
 7: <NA>  3
 8: <NA>  4
 9:   cc  1
10: <NA>  2
11: <NA>  3
12: <NA>  4
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
DTout <- copy(DTin)[, V1 := fifelse(V2 == 1, V1, rep("", 4))]
```

Comment: I think it should be `DTout <- copy(DTin)[, V1 := fifelse(V2 == 1, V1, "")]`

Comment: I see your point regarding V1 and V2, but fifelse requires argument 2 and argument 3 to be the same length. In yours, your argument 3 is shorter than argument 2 so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
DTout <- copy(DTin)[V2 != 1, V1:=""]
```